# I am stuck with my pokemon trading app practice in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

i started learning python in the last month and i am stuck with how to continue working on an idea i read about.
this will be only a simple training practice for me and also the first program i will do as OOP.

i entered to reddit app ideas to find some project to try to work on and one of these asked for a pokedex that allows you to check if someone has a pokemon that you need.

i was able to scrape the first gen 151 pokemon, create a player class and give each one 20 random pokemon.
now i want to give every player the option to check if player 2 has a pokemon that player 1 doesn't have and the reverse in order to see if they can do some trading but i am not sure how to do this. 
can someone please help me? :)

thanks in advance!

here is my code so far, i would also love to hear tips about ho i can make the current code better! :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import random

url = 'https://pokemondb.net/pokedex/national#gen-1'
req = requests.get(url)
page = req.text
Soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')

gen1_poke_names = [pokemon.get_text() for pokemon in Soup.find_all('',{'class':'ent-name'})[:151]]

class PokeScrape:
    def __init__(self):
        pass


class Player(PokeScrape):
    def __init__(self,name,poke_list):
        self.name = name
        self.poke_list = poke_list


Michael = Player('Michael',random.sample(gen1_poke_names,20))
print(Michael.name)
print(Michael.poke_list)

Daniel = Player('Daniel',random.sample(gen1_poke_names,20))
print(Daniel.name)
print(Daniel.poke_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easier to do using sets than lists, since it is straightforward to "subtract" one set from another. Suppose we have:

```py
Michael.poke_list = ['Bulbasaur', 'Squirtle', 'Pikachu']
Daniel.poke_list = ['Pikachu', 'Charmander']
```

Then:

```py
>>> michael_set = set(Michael.poke_list)
>>> daniel_set = set(Daniel.poke_list)
>>> michael_set - daniel_set
{'Bulbasaur', 'Squirtle'}
>>> daniel_set - michael_set
{'Charmander'}
```

So the set differences tell you which Pokémon each player has that the other doesn't.

Comment: Thanks! but the thing is i also want to also add a function in the player class that will allow someone to check if another player has a pokemon he doesnt have and this is where i get stuck :(  something like Michael.check(Daniel)

Comment: You can do this set subtraction, and check if the result is not empty, e.g. with `len(michael_set - daniel_set) > 0`.

Answer (score 0):

to check and return pokemon he has and you don't: (in Player class ofc)

```
def checkpoke(self, other_player):
    other_pokelist = other_player.pokelist
    result=[poke for poke in other_player.pokelist if poke not in self.pokelist]
    print("he has: {} but you don't".format(result))
```